# Convert callbackflow to sharedflow

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I am just starting with the usage of coroutines/flow (and kotlin in general) and I am struggling to convert a callbackFlow to a sharedFlow.

I have put together the simple example below just to show what I have tried, without success. My code is more complex but I believe this example reflects what are the issues of what I am trying to achieve.

```
fun main() = runBlocking {

    getMySharedFlow().collect{
        println("collector 1 value: $it")
    }

    getMySharedFlow().collect{
        println("collector 2 value: $it")
    }

}

val sharedFlow = MutableSharedFlow<Int>()

suspend fun getMySharedFlow(): SharedFlow<Int> {
    println("inside sharedflow")
    getMyCallbackFlow().collect{
        println("emitting to sharedflow value: $it")
        sharedFlow.emit(it)
    }
    return sharedFlow
}

fun getMyCallbackFlow(): Flow<Int> = callbackFlow<Int> {
    println("inside callbackflow producer")
    fetchSomethingContinuously {
        println("fetched something")
        offer(1)
        offer(2)
        offer(3)
    }
    awaitClose()
}

fun fetchSomethingContinuously(myCallBack: ()->Unit) {
    println("fetching something...")
    myCallBack()
}
```

The idea is that the `fetchSomethingContinuously` is only called once, independent the number of collectors of the sharedFlow. But as you can see from the output, collectors never gets the values:

```
inside sharedflow
inside callbackflow producer
fetching something...
fetched something
emitting to sharedflow value: 1
emitting to sharedflow value: 2
emitting to sharedflow value: 3
```

I looked in the [shareIn](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/share-in.html) operator, but not sure how to use it exactly.

How could I achieve something like this? Any tips would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So what you are missing here is the fact that calls to `collect`, `emit()` and `awaitClose()` are suspending and will finish only after the respective operation is done.

The function `getMySharedFlow()` doesn't even return in order to apply collect on it because it is collecting the `callbackFlow`, the `callbackFlow` is stuck at the call to `awaitClose()` which in turn doesn't finish because `fetchSomethingContinuously` did not end the callback with the `close()` function.

You need to create some explicit parallelism here, not live in the suspending world. A working variant of your sample code would be:

```kotlin
val sharedFlow = MutableSharedFlow<Int>()

suspend fun startSharedFlow() {
    println("Starting Shared Flow callback collection")

    getMyCallbackFlow().collect {
        println("emitting to sharedflow value: $it")
        sharedFlow.emit(it)
    }
}

fun main() = runBlocking<Unit> {

    launch {
        startSharedFlow()
    }

    launch {
        sharedFlow.collect {
            println("collector 1 value: $it")
        }
    }

    launch {
        sharedFlow.collect {
            println("collector 2 value: $it")
        }
    }

}


fun getMyCallbackFlow(): Flow<Int> = callbackFlow<Int> {
    println("inside callbackflow producer")
    fetchSomethingContinuously {
        println("fetched something")
        offer(1)
        offer(2)
        offer(3)
        //close() - call close here if you need to signal that this callback is done sending elements
    }
    awaitClose()
}

fun fetchSomethingContinuously(myCallBack: () -> Unit) {
    println("fetching something...")
    myCallBack()
}
```

Calls to `launch` allow for asynchronous execution of emitting and collecting values.

Also, about the `shareIn()` operator, it just creates a SharedFlow from the specified upstream, like you wanted to do. Also, you can specify when to start sharing with the `started` parameter. More on this [here](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/2047).

This is how you would use it in your example:

```kotlin
fun main() = runBlocking<Unit> {

    val sharedFlow = getMyCallbackFlow().shareIn(this, started = SharingStarted.Eagerly)

    launch {
        sharedFlow.collect {
            println("collector 1 value: $it")
        }
    }

    launch {
        sharedFlow.collect {
            println("collector 2 value: $it")
        }
    }

}


fun getMyCallbackFlow(): Flow<Int> = callbackFlow<Int> {
    println("inside callbackflow producer")
    fetchSomethingContinuously {
        println("fetched something")
        offer(1)
        offer(2)
        offer(3)
        //close() - call close here if you need to signal that this callback is done sending elements
    }
    awaitClose()
}

fun fetchSomethingContinuously(myCallBack: () -> Unit) {
    println("fetching something...")
    myCallBack()
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for the detailed explanation and the examples. They were very useful to be able to fix my issue :)

Comment: You're welcome! Respect++ for learning Kotlin, especially the more complicated topics, like Coroutines and Flows. Their design is amazing and definitely helpful for every project